# Flutter - animate the disappearance of a container out of a list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, animation, dart

I have a list of container widgets in a row, and each one has a small X on it that allows the user to delete that object out of the list. Right now, there is no animation and it is a bit jarring in the UI - could anyone tell me how to animate the object out of the list more gently and slide the other objects together in a nice way?

my minimal reproducible code is as follows:

```
var _images = List<Asset>();

...

Widget _buildImagesGrid() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black12,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount:
            isNotEmpty(_fileUploads) || isKeyboardOpen(context) ? 6 : 3,
        children: List.generate(_images.length, (index) {
          return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: Stack(children: [
                AssetThumb(
                  asset: _images[index],
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                ),

              Positioned(
                right: 0.0,
                top: -8.0,
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _images.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                  child: new Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 20.0,
                  ),
                  shape: new CircleBorder(),
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(24, 24)),
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                ),
              ),
              ]));
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: If I deleted the middle one, I would want it to animate out of the screen and for the right-most object to slide over to the left]

Comment: What properties would he animate since the height and width of his containers are determined by ```childAspectRatio```

Answer (score 0):

Definitly not the best way to do this, but works for me:

- wrap the Container with a unscrollable Listview
- wrap the Listview with a Expanded
- wrap the Expanded with a AnimatedContainer with the initial height of the original    Container
- animate the Container

Alternatively you can just use a normal Container and animate the height value of this via AnimationController.

Comment: The main effect I want to achieve is that if you delete the middle image, the right-most image slides to the left to replace it - this is whats not super clear to me

Comment: if I get this right, then this should work. If you delete the image in the middle then it should start shrinking and the next item in your grid view should replace it. If you want to make this in two steps (delete the image first, then let the image slide to the left),  make two animations (first let the Image go completely opaque, then shrink the Container)